# Java: Why a variable initialised by super class keeps value once object is created

Tags: java, initialization

I raised an issue at work, and simplified the code to reproduce it

```
public class Test {
    public void callTest(){ return; }
    public Test() { callTest(); }
}

public class Test1 extends Test{
    private Integer myInt;
    private Integer myNullInt = null;

    public Test1() {
      super();
    }

    @Override
    public void callTest() {
      myInt     = 25;
      myNullInt = 30;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return "Test1{myInt=" + myInt + ", myNullInt=" + myNullInt +'}';
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      Test1 t1 = new Test1();
      System.out.println(t1);
    }
}
```

With this a a result : Test1{myInt=25, myNullInt=null}

On my understanding, instance variable initializers should be executed after the call to super().
So why is 'myInt' getting a value.
And even how can it be possible ?

Comment: callTest() is called by your super constructor, which is not override yet... Notice that you override callTest() inside Test1, not Test. If it is called from super class, the void method will be called, if you do it inside Test1 and the overriden one will be called

Comment: @DynoZ The question is regarding how Java initializes instance fields. For instance, if the OP had done `private Integer myInt = 5;` then the value would remain `5` regardless of `callTest()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instance initializers are executed after the call to `super();` - that is why `myNullInt` is null. For `myInt` there is no instance initialzer involved.

The sequence of events is this:

- the main method creates a `new Test1()` object
- that means that the constructor of `Test1` is called
- that constructor in turn calls the `super` constructor `Test()`

  - the constructor of `Test` calls the `callTest();` method
  - since the object under construction is a `Test1` object, the `callTest` method from `Test1` is called
  - `Test1.callTest()` sets the `myInt` field to 25, the `myNullInt` field to 30
  - after that, the constructor of `Test` ends
- the constructor of `Test1` resumes and executes the field initializer `myNullInt = null;`
- since `myInt` doesn't have an initializer, its value is not changed

---

The process (including initialization with default values) is described in detail in the Java Language Specification, [Creation of New Class Instances](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5):

> Whenever a new class instance is created, memory space is allocated for it with room for all the instance variables declared in the class type and all the instance variables declared in each superclass of the class type, including all the instance variables that may be hidden ([§8.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3)).

> [If there is not sufficient space ...] Otherwise, all the instance variables in the new object, including those declared in superclasses, are initialized to their default values ([§4.12.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5)).

> Just before a reference to the newly created object is returned as the result, the indicated constructor is processed to initialize the new object using the following procedure:

> 1. / 2. [...]

> 3. [...] an explicit or implicit invocation of a superclass constructor [...]

> 4. Execute the instance initializers and instance variable initializers for this class [...]

> 5. Execute the rest of the body of this constructor. [...]

Comment: I always assumed there were implicit initializers when no explicit one was given. So `private Integer myInt;` is equivalent to `private Integer myInt = null;`. Apparently that assumption is wrong though.

Comment: @Slaw after allocating memory and before calling the constructors the JVM initializes the whole memory range of the object with a bit pattern that turns out to be `0` for numeric primitives, `false` for boolean values and `null` for reference types.

Comment: Huh. Interesting. I would have expected them to leave default values to the compiler rather than the JVM. But I suppose having the JVM do it makes more sense and is probably safer.

Comment: @ThomasKläger So this explains how they can have a value even if they are not yet initialized.
In other words, it turns out, even if the variables haven't yet been "initialized", the memory allocated allows the method callTest() to set a value to them.
And when their initialization comes, if there is no explicit value, they keep this ones.

Answer (score 4):

The order of execution in your code looks like this.

1. Constructor for `Test1` is called.
2. `super` invokes the constructor in `Test`.
3. Since the call started from `Test1`, the overridden `callTest` is called, which sets the value for `myInt` to 25 and `myNullInt` to 30.
4. `super` is completed, now proceeds to create the `Test1` object.
5. The instance variable for `myNullInt` is overwritten to null. Since there is no instruction for `myInt`, the value is unchanged.
6. `sysout` call invokes the `toString` and prints the `Test1` value.

The way instance variables are declared matters in inheritance.